# Hadoop Installation Problem

Tags: software-installation, 15.04, hadoop

```
This script is Deprecated. Instead use start-dfs.sh and start-yarn.sh
15/11/07 16:01:44 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
localhost: mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/local/hadoop/logs’: Permission denied
localhost: chown: cannot access ‘/usr/local/hadoop/logs’: No such file or directory
localhost: starting namenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-namenode-nikhil.out
localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 159: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-namenode-nikhil.out: No such file or directory
localhost: head: cannot open ‘/usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-namenode-nikhil.out’ for reading: No such file or directory
localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 177: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-namenode-nikhil.out: No such file or directory
localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 178: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-namenode-nikhil.out: No such file or directory
localhost: mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/local/hadoop/logs’: Permission denied
localhost: chown: cannot access ‘/usr/local/hadoop/logs’: No such file or directory
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-datanode-nikhil.out
localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 159: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-datanode-nikhil.out: No such file or directory
localhost: head: cannot open ‘/usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-datanode-nikhil.out’ for reading: No such file or directory
localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 177: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-datanode-nikhil.out: No such file or directory
localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 178: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-datanode-nikhil.out: No such file or directory
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
0.0.0.0: mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/local/hadoop/logs’: Permission denied
0.0.0.0: chown: cannot access ‘/usr/local/hadoop/logs’: No such file or directory
0.0.0.0: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-secondarynamenode-nikhil.out
0.0.0.0: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 159: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-secondarynamenode-nikhil.out: No such file or directory
0.0.0.0: head: cannot open ‘/usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-secondarynamenode-nikhil.out’ for reading: No such file or directory
0.0.0.0: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 177: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-secondarynamenode-nikhil.out: No such file or directory
0.0.0.0: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 178: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-secondarynamenode-nikhil.out: No such file or directory
15/11/07 16:02:06 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
starting yarn daemons
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/local/hadoop/logs’: Permission denied
chown: cannot access ‘/usr/local/hadoop/logs’: No such file or directory
starting resourcemanager, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-hduser-resourcemanager-nikhil.out
/usr/local/hadoop/sbin/yarn-daemon.sh: line 124: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-hduser-resourcemanager-nikhil.out: No such file or directory
head: cannot open ‘/usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-hduser-resourcemanager-nikhil.out’ for reading: No such file or directory
/usr/local/hadoop/sbin/yarn-daemon.sh: line 129: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-hduser-resourcemanager-nikhil.out: No such file or directory
/usr/local/hadoop/sbin/yarn-daemon.sh: line 130: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-hduser-resourcemanager-nikhil.out: No such file or directory
localhost: mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/local/hadoop/logs’: Permission denied
localhost: chown: cannot access ‘/usr/local/hadoop/logs’: No such file or directory
localhost: starting nodemanager, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-hduser-nodemanager-nikhil.out
localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/yarn-daemon.sh: line 124: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-hduser-nodemanager-nikhil.out: No such file or directory
localhost: head: cannot open ‘/usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-hduser-nodemanager-nikhil.out’ for reading: No such file or directory
localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/yarn-daemon.sh: line 129: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-hduser-nodemanager-nikhil.out: No such file or directory
localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/yarn-daemon.sh: line 130: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-hduser-nodemanager-nikhil.out: No such file or directory` <br />
hduser@nikhil:/usr/local/hadoop/sbin$ ^C <br />
hduser@nikhil:/usr/local/hadoop/sbin$ start-all.sh
This script is Deprecated. Instead use start-dfs.sh and start-yarn.sh
15/11/07 16:03:00 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
localhost: mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/local/hadoop/logs’: Permission denied
localhost: chown: cannot access ‘/usr/local/hadoop/logs’: No such file or directory
localhost: starting namenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-namenode-nikhil.out
localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 159: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-namenode-nikhil.out: No such file or directory
localhost: head: cannot open ‘/usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-namenode-nikhil.out’ for reading: No such file or directory
localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 177: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-namenode-nikhil.out: No such file or directory
localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 178: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-namenode-nikhil.out: No such file or directory
localhost: mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/local/hadoop/logs’: Permission denied
localhost: chown: cannot access ‘/usr/local/hadoop/logs’: No such file or directory
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-datanode-nikhil.out
localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 159: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-datanode-nikhil.out: No such file or directory
localhost: head: cannot open ‘/usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-datanode-nikhil.out’ for reading: No such file or directory
localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 177: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-datanode-nikhil.out: No such file or directory
localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 178: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-datanode-nikhil.out: No such file or directory
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
0.0.0.0: mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/local/hadoop/logs’: Permission denied
0.0.0.0: chown: cannot access ‘/usr/local/hadoop/logs’: No such file or directory
0.0.0.0: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-secondarynamenode-nikhil.out
0.0.0.0: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 159: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-secondarynamenode-nikhil.out: No such file or directory
0.0.0.0: head: cannot open ‘/usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-secondarynamenode-nikhil.out’ for reading: No such file or directory
0.0.0.0: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 177: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-secondarynamenode-nikhil.out: No such file or directory
0.0.0.0: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 178: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-secondarynamenode-nikhil.out: No such file or directory
15/11/07 16:03:23 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
starting yarn daemons
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/local/hadoop/logs’: Permission denied
chown: cannot access ‘/usr/local/hadoop/logs’: No such file or directory
starting resourcemanager, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-hduser-resourcemanager-nikhil.out
/usr/local/hadoop/sbin/yarn-daemon.sh: line 124: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-hduser-resourcemanager-nikhil.out: No such file or directory
head: cannot open ‘/usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-hduser-resourcemanager-nikhil.out’ for reading: No such file or directory
/usr/local/hadoop/sbin/yarn-daemon.sh: line 129: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-hduser-resourcemanager-nikhil.out: No such file or directory
/usr/local/hadoop/sbin/yarn-daemon.sh: line 130: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-hduser-resourcemanager-nikhil.out: No such file or directory
localhost: mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/local/hadoop/logs’: Permission denied
localhost: chown: cannot access ‘/usr/local/hadoop/logs’: No such file or directory
localhost: starting nodemanager, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-hduser-nodemanager-nikhil.out
localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/yarn-daemon.sh: line 124: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-hduser-nodemanager-nikhil.out: No such file or directory
localhost: head: cannot open ‘/usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-hduser-nodemanager-nikhil.out’ for reading: No such file or directory
localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/yarn-daemon.sh: line 129: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-hduser-nodemanager-nikhil.out: No such file or directory
localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/yarn-daemon.sh: line 130: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-hduser-nodemanager-nikhil.out: No such file or directory
```

I have been trying to install Hadoop 2.6.0 single node cluster in Ubuntu 15.04. When I run `start-all.sh`, I get the output as shown above. Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the user you are trying to run the script as a user that does not have write access to /usr/local/hadoop.

Did you install from repositories?

You will usually have a user specifically for hadoop that should be owner of /usr/local/hadoop (or wherever you put it) and then run the start-scripts as that user.